# How to query my need data by PSQL

Tags: database, compare, record, psql

From data

```
--------------------------
|  No |  Count |  Status |
| 001 |  3     | active  |
| 001 |  1     |complete |
| 002 |  3     | pending |
| 003 |  2     |complete |
| 004 |  3     | active  |
| 004 |  2     | pending |
| 004 |  1     |complete |
| 005 |  4     |  close  |
| 006 |  1     |  close  |
--------------------------
```

But my need query data .

```
--------------------------
|  No |  Count |  Status |
| 001 |  4     | active  |
| 002 |  3     | pending |
| 003 |  2     |complete |
| 004 |  6     | active  |
| 005 |  4     |  close  |
| 006 |  1     |  close  |
--------------------------
```

On condition

- sum count of No duplicate
- status priority order is  `active > pending > complete > close`

but status of three records is same No but Status not same
for exam

```
--------------------------
| 004 |  3     | active  |
| 004 |  2     | pending |
| 004 |  1     |complete |
--------------------------
```

we will select Status is First priority `active > pending > complete > close`

from data table `active` is best. result is

```
    --------------------------
    | 004 |  6     | active  |
    --------------------------
```

How to query by psql ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to count duplicates you need to list every entry that appears more than once. To get the count by a specific value you need to group by that value and then apply the count operator. You can then restrict that to only those results that have a count greater than 1.

The problem is that the query that collects the count must be a subquery, as you cannot use the calculated count in the where clause otherwise.

In your example I can see that there are duplicate entries in the count column. I assume that this is what you want to detect:

```
SELECT subquery.number_of_duplicates, subquery.Count
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS number_of_duplicates, Count
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Count
) AS subquery
WHERE subquery.number_of_duplicates > 1;
```

I really have no idea what you want to do with the status. You will have to improve the explanation of that part of your question.

Comment: Um.. sorry i'm not good in english but i will try again to explanation.